# Какие предметы необходимо знать программисту.

Tags: c#

Вот скажите я сейчас в 10-м классе, хочу в будущем стать C# программистом, на какие предметы делать большой упор, чтобы было легко поступить на работу(программиста)?

Comment: А почему **именно C#** ?

Comment: Ну как я читал "За ним будущее"

Comment: Наверное на сайте Майкрософт читал? Заапомни, тебе как программисту прийдется выучить несколько языков.

Comment: Это наверное Билл Гейтс так думает. А Python пробовали ?

Вообще программист должен знать много разных языков (двумя-тремя владеть хорошо). Язык это просто инструмент решения проблем заказчика.

**Правильная идея** состоит в том, чтобы для решения задачи использовать наиболее подходящий язык (их смесь).

Comment: Нет, я пробовал только VB 6.0, VB.NET, C# .NET, PHP(чуть чуть)

Comment: Да я вот когда переходил с VB.NET на C#.NET я так путался, очень сложно было, бела реальная "смесь языков", но постепенно привык, и пока не могу представить как это - "знать много языков".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Математика, Информатика, Английский язык, Физика. Естественно, остальные предметы тоже необходимы для всестороннего развития.

Comment: Я бы порядок поменял. Английский, Информатика, Физика, Математика.

Comment: Вообще то, тут есть исключения из правил. Мой одноклассник из вышеуказанных четырех предметов шарил лишь в информатике, остальные так себе. Зато кодит четко.

Comment: Это пока он не столкнулся с задачей, где вся теория изложена на английском, а ему надо еще и алгоритмы придумать.

Comment: ну да. или например если в задаче указано начертить график или гистограмму и т.п.

Comment: каратеееее =)
+ мат.ан, компьютерную арифметику, с физикой поспорил бы, есть разные программисты(это отличное определение, от кодера) и обычно они узкоспециализированые (если программист пишет на С++ игры, ИИ, и тд, врятли он сразу переключится на вебсервисы)

Comment: К этим предметам еще добавил бы Логику. Это часть математики, но такой полезный предмет, особенно в программировании.

Answer (score 4):

А почему **"хочу"**? В специальности программист нет возрастных/половых/расовых/политических ограничений. Поэтому нужно уже сейчас начинать кодить, читать листинги других программистов, участвовать в opensource проекте. Вариантов уйма. А там будет видно, что нужно.

В программировании, как и в практически любой другой специальности нельзя думать, что вот в школе я буду учить математику, потом пойду в университет, а потом пойду на работу. Те, кто так думает, потом ещё ищет работу и говорит, что все сложно и так далее.

Спросите к примеру любого хорошего врача. Он скорее всего с детства уже как не жаб резал, так котам раны заделывал. А потом уже решил быть доктором.

Не нужно думать, что если подучить какие то конкретные предметы, то это поможет. Скорее всего нет. Нужно равномерно учить все. К примеру, какое может иметь отношения география к 
 программированию, учить ее или нет? А никто не знает. Может завтра в GoogleMaps предложат поработать, а Австрию от Австралии отличить не получается... Или к примеру биологию - мне лично кажется, что вот вот и микробиология/генетика пересекутся с программированием, ведь днк - это та же программа, просто написанная немножко по другому. И будут программисты-биологи, к которым приходишь, что бы они "подебажили днк" и поправили, к примеру, форму носа:)...  Точно также можно подобрать  под любой предмет. Поэтому не стоит себя ограничивать каким-то набором предметов, а то завтра придется отказаться от заманчивого проекта. Может быть по этому, можно часто встретить отличного программиста, который окончил исторический факультет или социологию (хотя некоторые идут туда сознательно - их уровень интеллекта позволят им там без напряжения учится и не мешает заниматься любимым делом).

Поэтому, самый главный совет - "перестать боятся и начать кодить!" (© кажется Шилдт). И конечно же, развивать свое мышление.

Comment: Оу... какой текст! Многое себе выписал из текста, спасибо :) 

\Поэтому, самый главный совет - "перестать боятся и начать кодить!" (© кажется Шилдт). И конечно же, развивать свое мышление.

Вот в том то и дело, если знать как и что кодить, то можно и не бояться, а когда ты хочешь написать например прогу типо HyperCam, и не знаешь что даже подключать к проекту... вот тогда и начинаешь бояться, конечно может у меня такое потому что я учу C# 1,5 недели, может быть со временем это пропадет, кто его знает.

Comment: Ну 1,5 недели это не срок, со временем точно пропадет. Что кодить, чтобы научиться и не бояться ? Например, закодить десяток-другой стандартных библиотечных функций, используя только системные вызовы  (чисто с учебной целью), если это ввод-вывод и т.п.

Comment: "микробиология/генетика пересекутся с программированием" - прямо бальзам мне на душу как бывшему генетику. Кстати, уже сейчас в МГУ есть факультет биоинформатики. Компьютерный анализ сиквенсов ДНК - очень актуальная тема.

Answer (score 3):

учи больше чем один C#.
выучи С или С++.
также полезно знать ассемблер.
учись хорошо по всем предметам, хотя ударными конечно должны быть вышеуказанные(англ., Информатика, Физика, Математика), хотя у нас например такая училка Физики, что любуюю вещь тебе объяснит(по математике) лучше чем математичка.

Comment: Учту, а C# и С++, когда я буду учить C++, очень сложно будет привыкать к синтаксису C++?

Comment: Вместо C++ для начала (и разнообразия) после C# возьми C (он к машине ближе).

Comment: Т.е учить надо так
1.C#.NET
2.C
3.C++.NET?

Comment: ну да. если ты под  windows пишешь, то ты прав.
насчет привыкания, то точно не знаю, потому что я сначала выучил C++, а затем начал(и-то чуть-чуть) интересоваться С#. но мне кажется, что в C++ больше вольностей, которые, тем не менее, не делают язык хуже(а если верить статистике, то даже лучше)

Answer (score 2):

C# - это язык достаточно высокого уровня. Поэтому идеально для начала понять что находится более внизу, например изучить классический Си. Просто дело в том, что сейчас появляются программисты новой волны, которые может и понимают как написать ту или иную программу, а например задачи по булевой алгебре ставят их в тупик. Поэтому главное понять основы, понять как всё работает,  а потом двигаться дальше. Тем более после понимания этих основ, проблем с освоением новых языков быть не должно. Ведь хороший программист - это не тот, кто много знает, а тот кто быстро учится новому и применяет это на практике.

Comment: половину профессиональных java программистов битовые операции ставят в полный тупик:)